How should i deploy my full stack app. 2 different git repos or 2 different azure app services
So I'm am in charge of the frontend with angular of this webapp while someone else does the backend with django.
I am trying to implement CI/CD and deploy this app to azure using github actions but I dont really know how to do this efficiently.
I created a github repo and initialized the frontend and backends folders seperately and pushed the code to a dev branch in my git repo then created an azure account and created a resources-gp and also 1 azure app service and connected my github repo to it and selected python as workflow and it was connected but in my github repo i see this error:
Github error
Github same error
And here the frontend and backend are all in one repo but when creating the workflow i specified just python i assume that was just for the backend but even though i still see this errors above.
Can someone help me out here please?
THe workflow yml:
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - Workmayte

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.12'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'Workmayte'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_85AEAEFC8D224F25862264F17C61E0A5 }}


can you please share your git which has frontend with angular of this webapp while someone else does the backend with django . please share the yml file in above question in text format.

@Sampath I just added the yml file

please share your git hub link as well

https://github.com/Workmayte/workmayte

To Build and Deploy Angular + Django App follow below  steps:
Add below Frontend Setup and Build  using Node.js and Angular in yml file:
- name: Set up Node.js
  uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: '20.x'

- name: Install and build Angular frontend
  working-directory: angular-17-crud-example-master
  run: |
    npm install
    npm run build --prod
    mv dist/* ../post-back-do-front-backend-master/static/

I referred to these links for integrating the frontend and backend using Angular and Django.
After building the Angular app, the static files are moved into the Django backend's static folder:
mv dist/* ../post-back-do-front-backend-master/static/

Then add bleow Django database migrations :
- name: Run Django migrations
  working-directory: post-back-do-front-backend-master
  run: |
    source venv/bin/activate
    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate

Combine Frontend and Backend into a zip file:
- name: Prepare deployment package
  run: |
    zip -r release.zip post-back-do-front-backend-master

Change the Deployment Artifact Configuration as below :
name: Upload artifact uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3 with: name: fullstack-app path: release.zip


Below is a my sample GitHub Actions YAML file for building and deploying an Angular frontend with a Django backend to an Azure Web App:
name: Build and deploy Angular and Django app to Azure Web App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'
      - name: Install and build Angular frontend
        working-directory: angular-17-crud-example-master
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --prod
          mv dist/* ../post-back-do-front-backend-master/static/
      - name: Set up Python environment
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.9'

      - name: Install backend dependencies
        working-directory: post-back-do-front-backend-master
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
          pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Run Django migrations
        working-directory: post-back-do-front-backend-master
        run: |
          source venv/bin/activate
          python manage.py makemigrations
          python manage.py migrate
      - name: Prepare deployment package
        run: |
          zip -r release.zip post-back-do-front-backend-master

      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: fullstack-app
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: fullstack-app
      - name: Unzip artifact
        run: unzip release.zip
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'tejatyuu78888trrr'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE }}
          package: post-back-do-front-backend-master

Output:


